# UIWebView contents are not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, xcode6

I have a `UIWebView` on a `UIView` which loads content from server.

The `UIWebView` contents are not showing in screen.

What is wrong with my code?

```
vwWebView = [[UIView alloc]init];
vwWebView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, [GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH]-40,[GRAPHICS SCREEN_HEIGHT]-20);
vwWebView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
vwWebView.layer.borderColor =  [[UIColor colorWithRed:207.0 / 255.0
                                                green:207.0 / 255.0
                                                 blue:207.0 / 255.0
                                                alpha:1.0] CGColor];
vwWebView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
vwWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

m_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
m_webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
m_webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
m_webView.opaque = NO;
m_webView.delegate = self;
m_webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
m_webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[vwWebView addSubview:m_webView];

[self.view addSubview:vwWebView];

-(void)API_CALLBACK_TermsAndConditions:(NSDictionary *)responseDict
{
    NSString *strCondition = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[responseDict objectForKey:@"msg"]];
    NSString *loadString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body text=\"#FFA500\">%@</body></html>", strCondition];
    [m_webView loadHTMLString:loadString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: It is because maybe autoresizingMask isnt enough. You need to set frame and check.

Comment: can you first debug and check frame please, maybe GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH is zero or nil?

if everything is OK with frame please check API_CALLBACK_TermsAndConditions method.

update line below :

NSString *loadString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body text=\"#FFA500\">%@</body></html>", strCondition];
with line below :

NSString *loadString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body text=\"#FFA500\"><h2>TEST</h2>></body></html>"];
because content could be empty.

If this suggestions not fix let me know, after that we'll check other possibilities :)

Comment: webview is appearing..i tried what u suggested.but no success

Comment: You never actually set a frame to your `UIWebView` replace `m_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];` with `m_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, [GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH]-40,[GRAPHICS SCREEN_HEIGHT]-20)];` It's all well and good setting a `autoresizingMask` but if it doesn't have a frame to work with it's not going to work.